# Call to undefined method app\models\etc.. Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I have a problem. I don't understand where the error stems from. Sorry, but I'm new as a Yii2 developer.

This in my code in controller:

```
public function getIcons($status_id)
{
    $model = Orders::findOne($status_id);
    $days = getWorkingDays($model->update_at,date());

    $alert = 0;        //spunta
    if (($model->status_id == 2) && ($days >= 2)) $alert=1; //giallo

    if (($model->status_id == 3) && ($days >= 2)) $alert=1;
    if (($model->status_id == 4) && ($days >= 10)) $alert=1;

    if (($model->status_id == 5) && ($days >= 7)) $alert=1;
    if (($model->status_id == 5) && ($days >= 12)) $alert=2; //teschio

    if (($model->status_id == 6) && ($days >= 10)) $alert=1;
    if (($model->status_id == 7) && ($days >= 8)) $alert=1;

    if (($model->status_id == 9) && ($days >= 5)) $alert=1;
    if (($model->status_id == 9) && ($days >= 10)) $alert=2;

    if($alert = 0) $icons='check'; //spunta
    if($alert = 1) $icons='fa fa-exclamation';  //esclamativo
    if($alert = 2) $icons='bs-skull info-button-black';
    if($model->blocked = 1 && $model->paused = 1) $icons="dollar-sign"; //dollaro
    if($model->blocked = 1 && $model->paused = 0) $icons="dollar-sign";
    if($model->blocked = 0  && $model->paused = 1) $icons="dollar-sign";
    if ($model->save()) Helper::add_history(null, null, $obj_id, '', 'Update', 'Done', 0, 0, 'Order', 1, 0, '');

    return $this->redirect(['index']);
}
```

This's in view/index:

```
<?= $icon = Orders::getIcons($order->status_id)?>                           
<?= 
Html::a('<i class="fa fa-'.$icon.'"></i>', ['index', 'id' => $order- 
>id], [
'class' => 'btn btn-warning',
]); 
?>
```

In the view I have to update the status, and updating changes the icon.

This is the error I get:

> Call to undefined method backend\models\Orders::getIcons()

Comment: Please update your question with full error message.

Comment: my error: Call to undefined method backend\models\Orders::getIcons()    <?= $icon = Orders::getIcons($id); ?>

Comment: Then add missing `getIcons()` method in `backend\models\Orders` model.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to call a static function!!
Add static keywords to the definition of function getIcons()